# Is there any way to call function with parameters In react-native?

Tags: react-native

i want to know how to call function with parameters in arrow function

this is my code

```
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    number: 1
};

change_number = (type) => {
if(type === minus){
   this.setState({ number: this.state.number - 1 })
 }else{
   this.setState({ number: this.state.number + 1 })
 }
};

render() {
 return (
   <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
     <View style={styles.button}>
       <Button onPress={() =>{this.change_number}} title={"-"} />
     </View>
     <Text style={styles.text}>{this.state.number}</Text>
     <View style={styles.button}>
       <Button onPress={this.change_number } title={"+"} />
     </View>
   </View>
  );
 }
}
```

there are two button - and +

i want to do button event in minus and plus

When I click on the function I want to determine whether it is a minus function or a plus function.
Is there anyone you can help me with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. You just need to call change_number function with minus parameter

```
change_number = (type) => {
if(type === 'minus'){
   this.setState({ number: this.state.number - 1 })
 }else{
   this.setState({ number: this.state.number + 1 })
 }
};

render() {
 return (
   <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
     <View style={styles.button}>
       <Button onPress={() =>{this.change_number('minus')}} title={"-"} />
     </View>
     <Text style={styles.text}>{this.state.number}</Text>
     <View style={styles.button}>
       <Button onPress={this.change_number } title={"+"} />
     </View>
   </View>
  );
 }
}
```